# OnPublishEndAsync not triggering on CD Server

Tags: publishing

I am setting up an existing site to use separate authoring and delivery servers. We have configured the onPublishEndAsync event to use the web database, and check for threshold is set to true. When I publish the site, and look at the logs: My authoring server has rebuilt the indexes appropriately, however, the indexes on the CD server are out of date.

Is there a configuration that will force my CD environment to detect when it's source database has been published to and initiate at least an incremental build?

*Sitecore 8.0.150812* (also patched with https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/992608)

The Sitecore.ContentSearch.DefaultConfigurations.config has the following relevant setting:

```xml
<onPublishEndAsync type="Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.Maintenance.Strategies.OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy, Sitecore.Support.440383.449997"> 
    <param desc="database">web</param>
    <!-- Whether or not a full index rebuild should be triggered when the number of items in the EventQueue exceeds the number specified 
             in ContentSearch.FullRebuildItemCountThreshold. -->
    <CheckForThreshold>true</CheckForThreshold>
</onPublishEndAsync>
```

Here is  a portion of one of the custom indexes:

```xml
    <index id="custom_index"
             type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
        <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/eventIndexConfiguration" />
        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
          <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
          <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/intervalAsyncMaster" />
        </strategies>
        <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
          <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
            <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
          </policies>
        </commitPolicyExecutor>
        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
          <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/mysites/Home</Root>
          </crawler>
        </locations>
      </index>
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant config snippets please, on how you've set this up. Makes it easier to spot where the problem may be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While a lot of the suggestions were helpful, my issue ended up being related to migrating to different servers. Prior to inheriting this website, it appears that the database was consistently backed up and migrated across servers; from local, to staging, to production, and now a new production. The properties table in the core database was storing all instances (CD and CM server names). I ended up deleting all the records in that table. Once that happened, indexing improved. After that I was seeing a few intermittent issues potentially being caused by index locking - so I implemented the Switch on Rebuild strategy. Since making those two tweaks I am no longer experiencing issues.

Answer (score 18):

The most likely issue here is the scalability settings for the instance names. Scalability settings allow your different instances to listen to the shared event queue and know which ones to respond to.

### Delivery Scalability Settings

Your delivery instances should have a config patch with something like the snippet below. The instance name is not as important here, but the name of the publishing instance tells the delivery instance which events to listen for from the publisher:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
      <settings>
         <!-- INSTANCE NAME
            Unique name for Sitecore instance.
            Default value: (machine name and IIS site name)
         -->
         <setting name="InstanceName">
            <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
         </setting>
         <!-- PUBLISHING INSTANCE
            Assigns the instance name of dedicated Sitecore installation for publishing operations.
            When empty, all publishing operations are performed on the local installation of Sitecore.
            Default vaue: (empty)
         -->
         <setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
           <patch:attribute name="value">CM</patch:attribute>
         </setting>
      </settings>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

### Authoring Scalability Settings

The scalability settings on the authoring need to match for both publishing and instance name. This makes sure the right instance name goes into the logs, and also lets the authoring system know that it is the publisher. Your authoring instance should have a config patch with something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
   <sitecore>
      <settings>
         <!-- INSTANCE NAME
            Unique name for Sitecore instance.
            Default value: (machine name and IIS site name)
         -->
         <setting name="InstanceName">
            <patch:attribute name="value">CM</patch:attribute>
         </setting>
         <!-- PUBLISHING INSTANCE
            Assigns the instance name of dedicated Sitecore installation for publishing operations.
            When empty, all publishing operations are performed on the local installation of Sitecore.
            Default vaue: (empty)
         -->
         <setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
           <patch:attribute name="value">CM</patch:attribute>
         </setting>
      </settings>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

***NOTE:*** Based on details from https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/sitecore-publishing-stuck-on-initializing-after-applying-scalability-settings/

Comment: Thanks Jay. I added the patch files, and my show.config display:

Authoring Config:

        <setting name="InstanceName" value=""/>
        <setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance" value="CM"/>

CD:

         `<setting name="InstanceName" value="CM" patch:source="SwitchMasterToWeb.config"/>
        <setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance" value="CM"/>`

Comment: Do the values of InstanceName and PublishingInstance have to correlate to the IIS host name or sites node in any way?

Comment: I noticed in the log files, when the instance starts it logs the instance name as Server name + IIS container. So I am using that as the values. Still no dice, but I'll try rebuilding the index and full republish.

Comment: @MikeD the instance and publish instance name in the scalability setting can be different from the IIS. If you check in the event queue table you will see the entry CM. Since you will have many other servers, sitecore will automatically insert the instance name. The instance name acts as a reference in order for other servers to know the event has been triggered

Comment: Some useful links for my comment above: https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sitecore-event-queues/ and https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/sitecore-server-synchronization/

Comment: Here are my latest config patches.  
**CD:**  
`<setting name="InstanceName" value="sc8cd1" patch:instead="setting[@name='InstanceName']" />  
<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance" value="sc8cm1" patch:instead="setting[@name='Publishing.PublishingInstance']" />`  

**Author**  
`<setting name="InstanceName" value="sc8cm1" patch:instead="setting[@name='InstanceName']" />  
<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance" value="sc8cm1" patch:instead="setting[@name='Publishing.PublishingInstance']" />`  

Still not triggering an index on the CD wen I publish in author

Comment: Have you confirmed on ShowConfig.aspx of your CD that your settings have been applied?

Answer (score 8):

Events are delivered from one instance to another as records in `EventQueue` data table. By default Sitecore uses `Core` DB for storing these events, but that can be changed in config.

```xml
<eventing defaultProvider="sitecore">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Eventing.EventProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" systemDatabaseName="core"/>
  </providers>
</eventing>
```

Check that both these instances use shared `Core` DB. If that is not possible for any reason, set up SQL replication for Core database from `CM` to `CD` to synchronize events.

You can find more information regarding SQL replication in Sitecore documentation - [SQL Server Replication
Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/sql_server_replication_guide_sc63-64-a4.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry - Both instances do share the same core DB

Answer (score 8):

Other answers here very relevant, but also worth mentioning that **all** servers, database included, need their time synchronized.

Comment: Thanks @techphoria. I have confirmed, all three participating servers (CM, CD, DB) have the same time. I'm not sure aside from remoting in and looking and the clock, how synchronized you recommend - but they appear to be the same.

Answer (score 4):

There are different things that need to be verified. I have several blog post concerning this. Below is a brief overview of the several steps that you need to verified:

**1. Scalability Settings**
Supposed you have different CM and CD servers. You will need to define one of your CM server as a Job Server. You need to set the scalability settings as shown below:

CM Server

```xml
<setting name="InstanceName">
  <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
  <patch:attribute name="value">CM1</patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

On the Job Server

```xml
<setting name="InstanceName">
  <patch:attribute name="value">CM1</patch:attribute>
</setting>

<setting name="Publishing.PublishingInstance">
  <patch:attribute name="value"></patch:attribute>
</setting>
```

More info at [Scalability Setting](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/03/19/sitecore-scalability-setting/). Note that the instance name in other CM Scalability setting needs to be blank because sitecore will replace it with the machine name when inserting the record in the Database.

**2. Event Queue**
You need to check if the event queue is activated. This allows for different servers to execute their events when there is a new entry in the event queue table.

```xml
<eventQueue>
  <!-- Time between checking the queue for newly queued events. If new events are found they will be raised. -->
  <processingInterval>00:00:02</processingInterval>
</eventQueue>
```

More info at [Event Queue](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/sitecore-event-queues/)

**3. Server Synchronization**
Based on the number of items that have been published, your server needs to get in sync with the job server before being able to trigger the events. You can follow this [link](https://hishaamn.wordpress.com/2016/04/05/sitecore-server-synchronization/) to know how to check if all your servers are in sync.

EDIT 1

Change the following

```xml
configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/eventIndexConfiguration"
```

to

```xml
configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration"
```

Change the index type from LuceneIndex to SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex

Comment: Good stuff Hishaam. I have one CM and one CD.  Running your EQSTamp query shows me my CM has **EQStamp_sc8cm1=751578** and my CD has **EQStamp_sc8cd1=751578.**  

Both the CD and CM have 00:00:02 for processingInterval value. 
 
My CM has 'sc8cm1' set for both instanceName and Publishing Instance.  
My CD has 'sc8cd1' for instanceName and 'sc8cm1' for PublishingInstance.

Comment: Yes. This means that your server is in sync and the rebuild index should be triggered on your CD server.

Comment: Well shucks, those indexes just want to be stubborn. I made a content change, republished and verified the servers remained in sync. The indexes on the CD server have remained unchanged since last night when I manually re-indexed directly on the CD box. Hopefully its not a easter egg left by the previous dev team.

Comment: What index strategy are you using?

Comment: onPublishEndAsync. I noticed in my log files on the CD server, when I publish, it does trigger a cache clear. Periodically, I also see:

`Starting update of index for the database 'comment' (1 pending)`. This is interesting, I would think 'web' should be the database. I think the comment database is in place for analytics (I'm still absorbing what I've inherited)

Comment: From the configuration file you specified above, you are using the master database in the custom index. It should be web normally and you need to specify only one strategy.

Comment: Good catch, that is true, on the CM server it is using Master, but in the CD it is patched to use web. I agree it makes more sense to use web in both environments for this custom index. I'll update it and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Your CD server should use the web database.

Comment: The CD has been using the web database all along. For giggles, I updated the custom index on the CM server to use "web" as well, but it still did not trigger anything.

Comment: From the index manager, has the time stamp been updated. Also, try to trigger an incremental publish and see if it does rebuild

Comment: By default, all event are registered in the core database eventqueue table. After a publish is completed, check the core db eventqueue table to see if the index start event is registered

Comment: The index manager in CM does show a recent updated date. The indexing manager on CD also shows updated (the document counts differ). There is no recent crawl activity being recorded in the crawl log.

Comment: This means that the Index on CD has been rebuilt. It is normal that the documents count differs since on CM you are using intervalAsyncMaster Strategy

Comment: the Core event queue does show index start events. All of the recent entries with %IndexingStarted% are logged under the CM instanceName.

Comment: This is why the PublishingInstance Name for the CD server should be the Instance Name of the CM Server. So, it seems that your indexes are getting rebuilt on CD. Just make sure that the setting `<setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true"/>` from Sitecore.config in the App_Config folder has value `true`

Comment: Yep the cd server has <setting name="EnableEventQueues" value="true"/>
Yep the values seem to line up with the docs Ive been reading. But the indexes in the folder are not updating, and the crawl logs show now recent activity.

Comment: So does the indexes on CD being rebuilt? If the time stamp are updated, it means that the indexes are rebuilt

Comment: nope, the time stamps are all from last night's manual rebuild.

Comment: Please see the edited 1 answer

Comment: I cannot make those changes - the custom index I used has calculated fields that need processing. However, I enabled the logs to capture debug info, and am wondering if this sheds any light? After a Authoring publish, the crawling logs on the CD server do reflect a triggered response. But it thinks the even queue is empty?  

`6512 18:29:20 DEBUG [Index=event_pages] OnPublishEndAsynchronousStrategy triggered.`  

`6512 18:29:20 DEBUG [Index=event_pages] Event Queue is empty. Incremental update returns`

Comment: Do you have verbose logging activated? I am not sure if this is present in Sitecore v8 but check if there is a config file in the include folder whose nane contains verbose logging or from the patch 449997