# Custom index, stategy to publish items under a certain path

Tags: publishing, indexing

We have this custom index that only contains pages for one section of the content tree. We want it setup so that publishing items under this path reindexes those items automatically. This seems like it should be default behavior but it is not working - we publish the items and no reindex happens. We can tell because old content is still shown on the site for these items, and the correct content is shown after rebuilding the entire custom index.

Our configuration is currently as follows:

```
<index id="redacted_centers" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider" patch:source="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Web.config">
<param desc="name">$(id)</param>
<param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
<!--
 This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id 
-->
<param ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" desc="propertyStore" param1="$(id)"/>
<configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultLuceneIndexConfiguration"/>
<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
<!--
 NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order 
-->
<strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync"/>
</strategies>
<commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
<policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ModificationCountCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<Limit>300</Limit>
</policy>
</policies>
</commitPolicyExecutor>
<locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
<crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
<Database>web</Database>
<Root>/sitecore/content/centers</Root>
</crawler>
</locations>
<enableItemLanguageFallback>false</enableItemLanguageFallback>
<enableFieldLanguageFallback>false</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
</index>
```

What configuration would be needed to make items get reindexed when they are published?

Comment: Is the issue only happening on this index or is it all indexes? It may be that the server event queue isn't picking up the publish:end:remote event. I'd check your sitecore config. And check your event queue  and jobs are being processed.

Comment: Your configuration looks a lot like the OOTB `sitecore_web_index` except by one detail or two. Are you able to make the OOTB `sitecore_web_index` work properly or not even that?

Comment: Is the issue that your cd server does not reindex or is this all on one server.

Comment: @MarkGibbons I don't know if it's happening for other indexes, and I'm not sure how to check - the custom index is the only one we are using the content search API in correlation with. My `publish:end:remote` event element has two handlers, `HtmlCacheClearer` and `RenderingParametersCacheClearer`. What specifically should I be looking for in `sitecore.config`?

Comment: @HugoSantos Not sure if this is an issue with other indexes as well... see my above comment.

Comment: @ChrisAuer There are two servers in a load balancer, but each server manages both CM & CD.

Comment: @MarkGibbons - Correction. We are using content search API for blog posts as well, which uses the web index. Duplicating a blog post and publishing the item puts it on the site immediately, so I think the web index is being updated for that item after it is published.

Comment: Can you please review this question to see if you don't have an index issue as much as your servers are not sending events to each other. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/1052/onpublishendasync-not-triggering-on-cd-server

Comment: @ChrisAuer If I have CM and CD on the same servers, how could it be an issue with servers communicating?

Comment: You said you had two servers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89696/discussion-between-paul-and-chris-auer).

Comment: We just tried doing a republish on some other items in this same section of the content tree and it did rebuild the index files (and fix an issue with outdated content). Was the solution to simply republish instead of smart publish? Is smart publish supposed to rebuild index files?